# Get SubArray Name from Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My array structure is like this

```
Array1          
    [0]     
         [0]  proto 
         [1]  0.141 
                    +[0]
                    + __proto
    [1]     
         [0]  proto 
         [1]  0.142 
                     +  [0]
                     +  __proto
```

I want to retrieve SubArrays ( 0.141[] , 0.142[] ).. I did that successfully with this code

```
var GroupedSoft = [];
    $.each(result, function (index, value1) {
        $.each(value1, function (index1, value2) {
            GroupedSoft.push(value2[0]);
        });
    });
```

but SubArray Name (0.141 , 0.142) is not present come in New collection .. I need the Name of the SubArrays

like :

```
GroupedSoft = [0.141[array elements]
              0.142[array elements] ]
```

Can it be possible ... ??

Answer (score 0):

0.141 is the value stored in Array1[0][1], not the associated name.

You probably want Array1[0][1][0] for your 0.141 and Array1[1][1][0] for 0.142

Or in your .each you could remove the nested .each with:

```
$.each(result, function (index, value1) {
  GroupedSoft.push(value1[1][0]);
});
```